# Washing machine drain leak / back up

Tags: dryer, washing-machine, laundry, back-up

Hi I recently bought a new Beko washing machine with dryer (model WD75141), just after 5-6 washes I saw water leakage on the floor, most probably drain water by the looks of it.

I am no expert my question is does this water also back flow into the laundry and subsequently the laundry is still dirty?

The drain pipe goes to a drain hose around 90cm high the same height as the washing machine and in the instructions it says maximum 90cm.

I saw the water leakage mid cycle, and afterwards I saw the washing machine removing water and filling drum with new water and spinning because in this cycle I did not see detergent bubbles in water.

**My question if the washing machine does that does it mean laundry is dirty? I am not sure if there could be a backup of water.**

Since the machine is a washer-dryer, at the end clothes were less dry than usual because the clothes got wrapped into a bed sheet which perhaps prevented drying, I am not sure. This drying less happened to me once before with another washing machine because of the same bed sheet.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] your post and use StackExchange's own hosting to embed your picture(s) directly into the post. A lot of people don't like going to link-shortened URLs because there's no telling what might be hiding there. Also, it's easier for people to take a look because there is no additional clicking around. Additionally, odds are good that clothes that end up wrapped up in a sheet won't dry as well, no matter what dryer you put them in.

Comment: "*does this water also back flow into the laundry and subsequently the laundry is still dirty?*"  We can not tell that from here.  The first step is to find out where or how  and when it  is leaking. Pull it  out and run it so you can watch to see if you tell where or how  and when it  is leaking. If the water comes for underneath then you may have to remove an access panel to see.

Comment: @AlaskaMan i pulled it a little bit and the water seem to be coming from the bottom and not from the water inlet or the drain outlet which is as high as the washing machine itslef, i checked the door and the soap drawer and the lint filter box , but these seem fine , something underneath the washer seems broken.

Comment: Check the connection of the drain hose to the pump outlet on the back/bottom/inside of the machine (wherever it is).  That is the usual location of this kind of leak.  If that's not it, and you said you checked the other connections, then it would be the drum.